# How to pass custom variables to a service coded in python?

Tags: python, twitter, service, pywin32

I am working with `win32serviceutil` to create a service based application in windows. I set up a service which runs the twitter streaming api (tweepy) code. I would like have an option to provide the search term for tweets from commandline. I am not understanding how to setup custom options for win32serviceutil.

I want to have something like this

```
$python PySvc.py start --search_term
```

so based on the search term i filter tweets.

```
class PySvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):  
# you can NET START/STOP the service by the following name  
_svc_name_ = "PySvc"  
# this text shows up as the service name in the Service  
# Control Manager (SCM)  
_svc_display_name_ = "Python Test Service"  
# this text shows up as the description in the SCM  
_svc_description_ = "This service writes stuff to a file"  

def __init__(self, args):
    i = 0
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)  
    # create an event to listen for stop requests on  
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)


# core logic of the service     
def SvcDoRun(self):  
    import servicemanager
    twitterStream[i].filter(track=['car'])
    i = i + 1

# called when we're being shut down      
def SvcStop(self):
    i = i - 1
    twitterStream[i].disconnect()
    # tell the SCM we're shutting down  
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)  
    # fire the stop event  
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)      


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(PySvc)
```